# What is the verb for turning something into a hologram?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

There is an apple.  I turn that apple into a hologram.  What am I doing?

I hologrammed the apple?  I holographed it?  (Auto-correct says no.)

Comment: This may come as a surprise to you, but there are hundreds of different  databases used by hundreds of different auto-correct algorithms.  don't trust any of them.

Comment: You did not turn the apple into a hologram. You may have created a hologram based on the apple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Holography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holography) is the process of producing holograms.

Perhaps then, by analogy with *photography*, where we *photograph* something, then you *could* say that you **"holographed"** something to turn it into a *hologram*.

And, guess what, it's actually in the dictionary:
http://www.dictionary.com/browse/holographed

The lesson?  Auto-correct is not the ultimate authority on language.  This site is!  (Just joking).

Comment: You joke, but I would sooner trust this site than I would Webster. Thanks!

Comment: @Evorlor but we get our sources from (the likes of) Webster!

Comment: @marcellothearcane which means its (the likes of) you that validate Webster!